# nohup can't save the pid of the process into file with xargs command

Tags: bash, 20.04, nohup, xargs

In the script that I am building I am having problem saving the pid to file.

If run in the terminal the command below:

```
nohup mvn spring-boot:run > $HOME/logs/app.log 2>&1 & echo $! > $HOME/pids/app.pid
```

I am unable to this `with xargs` command like below:

```
echo "dirA" | xargs -L 1 -I {}  sh -c "cd '{}'; echo 'Changed directory to' '{}';
nohup mvn spring-boot:run > $HOME/logs/app.log 2>&1 & echo $! > $HOME/pids/app.pid; "
```

The app.logs file are generated successfully and have the correct content. Meanwhile the app.pid is generated with empty content.

I will appreciate any help in figuring out this problem.

Regards,
Rando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes around your `sh -c "..."` command allow `$!` to be expanded by the interactive shell.

Try

```
echo "dirA" | xargs -L 1 -I {}  sh -c '
   cd "$1"; echo "Changed directory to $1"; 
   nohup mvn spring-boot:run > $HOME/logs/app.log 2>&1 & echo $! > $HOME/pids/app.pid;
' sh {}
```

There's no need to quote `{}` in most shells.

Comment: After applying this changes, it gave me error : Bad substitution.  Below is how i changed the  command:                                                                                                         
``` echo "${directories[$i]}" | xargs -L 1 -I {}  sh -c 'cd "$1"; echo "Changed directory to $1" ; nohup ${commands[$i]} > $HOME/logs/${directories[$i]}.log 2>&1 & echo $! > $HOME/pids/${directories[$i]}.pid; ' sh {} ```

Comment: @RandoShtishi that's a whole different issue - `sh` doesn't support arrays

Comment: I have this command :   ```echo "${directories[$i]}" | xargs -L 1 -I {}  sh -c "cd '{}'; echo 'Changed directory to' '{}'; nohup ${commands[$i]} > $HOME/logs/${directories[$i]}.log 2>&1 & echo  $! > $HOME/pids/${directories[$i]}.pid; "``` and it is working, beside the problem that does not save the pid

Comment: @RandoShtishi if you insist on doing it like that (which relies on the parent `bash` shell to expand arrays insde the `sh -c`) **which I don't recommend**, then you can selectively prevent premature expansion by escaping ex. `echo \$!`

Comment: Thank u so much @steeldriver.